# Create special progress bar for bootstrap slider

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, slider

I have a bootstrap slider set in my site in which I would like to add a timer progress bar for sliders. But the bar I need to create is a little different from the standard.

Basically, it's a transparent half circle with dotted border. Each dot of the border will get filled with white color to show the progress.
Do you know any way how I can do this?

```
<div id="event-slider" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

    <div class="carousel-inner"> 
        <!-- begin carousel-slide -->  
        <?php
        $slides = xs_get_option('theme_options', 'main_slider');
        $active = 'active';
        foreach ($slides as $arr) {
            echo '<div class="item ' . $active . '"> <img src="' . $arr['img_src'] . '" alt="' . $arr['title'] . '" class="img-responsive" /> </div>';
            $active = '';
        }
        ?>
        <!-- end carousel-slide --> 
    </div>
    <!-- end carousel-inner --> <div class="progressBar"></div> 
    <!-- Controls --> 
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#event-slider" data-slide="prev"> <i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i></a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#event-slider" data-slide="next"> <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post your code in your question.

Comment: sorry, was struggling with the editor. But i've posted it now :)